# Sorting a string array from any character position

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Working with vb 2008 I need to sort an array of strings: (for example:)

```
dim list1() as String={"CONE0Z08TTTBALL","BARE0U04TTTBALL",  
             "APTN0S01TTTBALL","SPTN0K02TTTBALL"}
```

sorted from 5th character (not first):

1. SPTN0K02TTTBALL
2. VPTN0S01TTTBALL
3. BARE0U04TTTBALL
4. CONE0Z08TTTBALL

There is any way using the Array class sort?

Comment: `SPTN0K02TTTBALL` isnt in the array - is that a typo?

Comment: Repaired! copypaste error!

Comment: but now, `VPTN0S01TTTBALL` isnt in the list...I get the drift though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq to do that.  I changed `APTN0K02TTTBALL` to `SPTN0K02TTTBALL` since that looks like a typo.

```
Dim list1() As String = {"CONE0Z08TTTBALL", "BARE0U04TTTBALL",
     "APTN0S01TTTBALL", "SPTN0K02TTTBALL"}
Dim result = list1.OrderBy(Function(q) q.Substring(5)).ToArray

For Each s As String In result
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Output:

> SPTN0K02TTTBALL
>   APTN0S01TTTBALL
>   BARE0U04TTTBALL
>   CONE0Z08TTTBALL

Note: If by 5th character, you meant 1-based, change the substring argument (which is 0 based) .  Also, this is an alpha sort, so if you want to sort by the value of a numeral, you should also convert to integer.  Not sure which you mean.

[ryanyuyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu) kindly wrote you this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/20wEHk)

Comment: So... as you were working on this answer, I was creating a demo.  Since my code ended up being almost identical to yours, you can use it if desired.  [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/20wEHk)

Comment: nice, I added it.  I used to write lots of those, but looking at the view count it seems that VB people never look at them. Odd.  @ryanyuyu

Comment: Thanks for your help. Numbers are treated as char, so I thing it will work.